# Is there any way to render in top to bottom order at vscode git graph extension?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

In vscode git graph extension, the commits log are ordered by bottom to top.

[image]

But I want to look up with top to bottom order.
I think there is no way to set like this in option... But is there any way to setting like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Git Graph extension for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mhutchie.git-graph) does not have any visible setting option to manage the display sort order indeed, and yet there seems to be one.

That was requested in [`mhutchie/vscode-git-graph` issue 117](https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph/issues/117)

> From an implementation perspective, it should just be a matter of retrieving the value of the new setting and passing the corresponding argument into the DataSource.getGitLog() method (currently it uses the [`--date-order` argument here](https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph/blob/d2fef4ce2fa246caa509b8744d5756cea5198989/src/dataSource.ts#L376)). The only constraint posed by the graph rendering algorithm is that for each commit, all of its parent commits must occur before it.

From [issue 304](https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph/issues/304) "Change commit-ordering from the Git Graph View" should be in [v1.24.0-beta.0](https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph/issues/304#issuecomment-636296981)

See [`package.json`](https://github.com/mhutchie/vscode-git-graph/blob/f025c1a31a0be2cadc3ea753f8032342a904bbb5/package.json#L777-L788)

```json
"git-graph.repository.commits.order": {
    "type": "string",
    "enum": [
        "date",
        "author-date",
        "topo"
    ],
    "enumDescriptions": [
        "Show commits in the commit timestamp order.",
        "Show commits in the author timestamp order.",
        "Avoid showing commits on multiple lines of history intermixed."
    ],
    "default": "date",
    "markdownDescription": "Specifies the order of commits on the Git Graph View. See [git log](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log#_commit_ordering) for more information on each order option. This can be overridden per repository via the Git Graph View's Column Header Context Menu."
},
```

It does not address the *reverse* order you are after though.